# Android: Cancel Volley request during execution due to slow connection

Tags: android, android-volley, timertask

I'm using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#send) in Android in order to make requests including fetching relatively large amount of data. I want to make timer of 5 seconds and if after it the request not returned - it probably means that there is slow connection and therefore I want to cancel the request. So far what I did:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
VioozerVolleyRequestFactory mFactory = new VioozerVolleyRequestFactory(this);
RequestQueue mQueue = VioozerVolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mQueue.cancelAll("MY_TAG");
    }
}, 5000};
Request<String> request = mFactory.createRequest(RequestType, 
    new Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           timer.cancel();
           //...
        }
    },
    new ErrorListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(String response) {
          timer.cancel(); 
          //...
        }
    }, extra);
request.setTag("MY_TAG");
mQueue.add(request);
```

My question: It seems that the request not canceled. The request is executed so the build in method `cancelALL(TAG)` not relevant here. How can I still achieve my requirement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Volley request timeout is set to 2500ms and it makes 1 retry per request.

You need to override DefaultRetryPolicy of Request.

for example:

Wait for 5000ms and do not perform any retry.

`request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,0,1f));`

Ref: [DefaultRetryPolicy.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/src/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java)

Comment: What is the mechanism of the execution? first we push it to the queue, then it waits there to execution. when it finally in execution (let's say execution itself takes 2 sec) after 1 sec I want to cancel it, so I send cancel(). what will happen?

Comment: that request's response will be ignored when it arrives.
To know more how it works internally:
[Volley: Easy, Fast Networking for Android](https://youtu.be/yhv8l9F44qo?t=20m2s)

Comment: Thanks, this led me to new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838724/android-volley-pros-cons-overriding-defaultretrypolicy-of-request