# Android Volley: Pros/Cons overriding DefaultRetryPolicy of Request

Tags: android, android-volley

By [default Volley request](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/src/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java) timeout is set to 2500ms and it makes 1 retry per request.

I wonder if it's a good thing to override it, let's say request timeout is set to 5000ms and 2 retries per request?

What are the reasons default timeout is 'just' 2.5 sec? 
Why 'only one' retry? It seems not enough, but perhaps there are good reasons hiding common best practises.

I'm tuning to considerations in the level of http, networking, routing etc. (NOT Android UI/UX).

EDIT: Example - If I set the timeout to 5 sec, is it possible waste of time because in some http level if the connection is NOT OK so the average response time to know this is only 2 sec? What are these http details I need to consider while overriding DefaultRetryPolicy?

Thanks,