# How to stop volley Request after 1 min

Tags: android, android-volley

In my application, I made a volley request and it is working fine, but when the response does not reach the user, the loader keeps loading and it doesn't stop. What should I do? How do I stop volley requests after 1 min if the response is nothing?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464832/how-to-cancel-volley-request-if-there-is-no-response-in-10-seconds/52464951

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793963/6176507

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossain if those contain the answers to this question then you should flag this as a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to cancel volley request if there is no response in 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464832/how-to-cancel-volley-request-if-there-is-no-response-in-10-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement the ErrorListener and setRetryPolicy method and dismiss the progress in  onErrorResponse method

```
    JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
    url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressdialog.dismiss()
            Log.d(TAG, "V_Error: " + error.getMessage());
             /*if (volleyError.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                // Show timeout error message
             }*/
        }
     });

     myRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
             7000,//Socket time out in milies
             DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
             DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```